# Why local storage deletes data with toggled checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to make a to-do list. I'm in the middle of a process and get the following problem:

1. I render a todo from input to a page - works fine.
2. I save todos in local storage - works fine.
3. I load todos from local storage - works fine, BUT when I tick a checkbox on a todo and refresh the page local storage deletes that particular todo. Can't figure out what's going on

HTML:

```
<body>
    
<ul id="list">
    
</ul>

<form action="submit" id="task-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type your task here and click 'Add a Task'" id="task-input">
    <button type="submit" id="add-button" > Add a Task </button>
</form>

<template id="template">
    <li class="list-item" data-todo-id="">
        <label class="list-item-label">
           <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
           <span list-item-text> Task text is here </span>
        </label>
           <button type="button"> Delete </button>
     </li>
</template>

</body>
```

JS:

```
let button = document.querySelector('#add-button')
let todoInput = document.querySelector('#task-input')
let template = document.querySelector('#template')
let list = document.querySelector('#list')
let LOCAL_STORAGE_PREFIX = 'TO-DO LIST APP'
let LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = `${LOCAL_STORAGE_PREFIX}-todos`
let todos = [];
let savedTodos = loadTodo();
savedTodos.forEach(renderTodo)

button.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    let date = new Date;

    let todo = {
        name : todoInput.value,
        complete : false,
        id : date.valueOf() }

    todos.push(todo)
    saveTodo();
    renderTodo(todo)

    console.log(todo)
    todoInput.value = ''
})

function renderTodo(todoName){
    let templateClone = template.content.cloneNode(true)
    let todoText = templateClone.querySelector('[list-item-text]')
    todoText.innerText = todoName.name
    list.appendChild(templateClone)
}

function saveTodo(){
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY,JSON.stringify(todos)) 
}

function loadTodo(){
   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) || [] 
}
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stakc Overflow! seems weird to me that the checkbox makes the task disappear, since in reality the checkbox has no listeners attached

Comment: Hi, thank you! Exactly , just can't wrap my head around it

Comment: The ticking of the checkbox probably doesn't matter at all. One issue with your code is that you don't initialize `todos` with the possible value stored in the localStorage, you always reinitialize it to a new empty array. This means that at next page refresh, you'll load only the ones that were added from the last session, not the ones before. In other words: first load, create "task1". Reload. -> "task1" is shown. Create "task2". Reload. Only "task2" is shown, because "task1" was not part of `todos` when "task2" got saved.  `todos` should be `savedTodos`.

Comment: you're absolutely right, friend. My bad. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox doesn't have any event handlers attached, so checking/unchecking it will have no effect on the todos. However, you have a bug in your code, which will lead to all your previously saved todos being deleted if you add a new one. The checkbox thing, I believe was a co-incidence.

```
let todos = [];
let savedTodos = loadTodo();
```

Here two different arrays are being created, `savedTodos` contains the todo lists parsed from local storage. And an empty array called `todos`. The list of todos in savedTodos also gets added to dom on next line.

So far so good..

```
...
    todos.push(todo)
    saveTodo();
    renderTodo(todo)
...
```

However, in your `addTodo` function (add button event handler), when you add a new todo it is added to the (currently empty) `todos` array, and then is also written back to the local-storage. At this point, the existing todos will show in DOM, but have been deleted from local-storage. When you refresh the page, only the Todos added in the last session will show.

To fix this, I's recommend merging the `todos` and `savedTodos` array, and having only one of those.

```
...
let allTodos = loadTodo();
allTodos.forEach(renderTodo)

// in addTodo function (add button event handler)
   ...
   allTodos.push(todo);
   ...

// in saveTodo function 
   localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY,JSON.stringify(allTodos));
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for the detailed answer!